# How do I make the loop finish when an error is thrown inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a loop, and somewhere in the loop, I get an exception or error. How do I keep the loop going?

```
Foos.each do |foo|
  ....
  # Random error/exception thrown here
  ....
end
```

Should I have a `rescue` block in the loop? Will that make the loop finish? Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use add a `begin/rescue` block. I am not sure there is other ways to do keep loop going if an error is raised.

```
4.times do |i|
  begin
    raise if i == 2
    puts i
  rescue
    puts "an error happened but I'm not done yet."
  end
end
# 0
# 1
# an error happened but I'm not done yet.
# 3
#=> 4
```

Since your title in the other hand ask for a way to ends the loop.
If you want the loop to ends in the `rescue`, you can use `break`.

```
4.times do |i|
  begin
    raise if i == 2
    puts i
  rescue
    puts "an error happened and I'm done."
    break
  end
end
# 0
# 1
# an error happened and I'm done.
#=> nil
```